# self executing function for javascript control

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, function

I am building an asp.net c# application that is heavily reliant on javascript and in particular jquery for usability.

I want to go with a namespaced object oriented approach for my javascript and so far I think I have achieved such.

For example I have the following setup for my global js file with common functions.

```
 (function (NS, $, undefined) {

  // javascript here   

 }
 (window.NS = window.NS || {}, jQuery));
```

Now I want to introduce similar for my controls where I work on the basis of 1 control = 1 javascript file.

I have seen multiple ways in jquery for the self executing of the jquery function and at present I have set up my javascript controls like follows.

```
$(function() { 
  // javascript here
 });
```

What is the best approach for the controls javascript - should I set it up like the global surround - as I want to be able access my NS namespace within the controls javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set them up like this:

```
(function($) {
   // javascript here 
   // NS.MyOtherJs.doSomething();
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Do I need to pass in a reference to NS in the self executing function?

Comment: Nope, since NS is in global scope already. Make sure script for `NS` runs first though.